# Python Help. How do I do this?

Tags: python

Implement a function, `int_div(x, y)`, that performs integer division by first rounding the two arguments to the nearest integers, and then performs integer division. This function should only return int, but can take both int and float as inputs.

```
def int_div(x, y):
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    round(x)
    round(y)
    return x // y
    raise NotImplementedError()

assert(int_div(2, 1) == 2)
assert(int_div(2, 1.4) == 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't assign the `round`ed values back to anything, you can reassign back to `x` and `y` before performing the division.

```
def int_div(x, y):
    x = round(x)
    y = round(y)
    return x // y
```

Also no point in the `raise` as any code after a `return` does not execute.

Comment: May I ask something general to you

Comment: Sure you can ask whatever you'd like

Comment: Am I crazy or do some people use this to ask questions and some people on here to answer as fast as possible like its a game, I am a practitioner of the latter, or am I imagining this scenario... Although me trying to keep up has improved my skills so vastly I feel like treating it as a game I've improved so much from never coding 30 days ago v if I had spent all that time in a book

Comment: Don't get hung up on how fast you can answer or how many points you get on this site. That isn't the purpose of the site and it will only lead to frustration when you feel like you didn't get as many votes as you "deserved". Just answer questions to be helpful to those learning, especially since it helps you learn in the process.

Comment: Okay so there are like yourself people just geniunely helping who are also incredibly fast xD

Answer (score 1):

```
# python3 solution

def int_div(x, y):
  x = round(x)
  y = round(y)
  return x // y

# python2 solution

def int_div(x, y):
  x = round(x)
  y = round(y)
  return int(x / y)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def int_div(x, y):
    return round(x)//round(y) # // means integer division in python
```